# React Native param not updating

Tags: react-native, parameters

I am passing the params with the navigation screen to render a particular screen based on param value. I have an empty state in a screen that stores the incoming param but the state is not updating. The render method is rendering the else condition option since it is getting the initial state empty only.

Here is my code:

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image, ImageBackground } from 'react-native'

const bgImage = require('../../assets/background.png')


export default class Home extends Component {

    render() {

        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={bgImage} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{marginVertical: 15}} 
                    onPress={()=>navigate('Dashboard', {param:'sales'})}>
                    <Image 
                        source={require('../../assets/sales.png')}
                        style={{borderRadius: 20, width: 300, height: 90}}
                    />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={()=>navigate('Dashboard', {param:'claims'})}>
                    <Image
                        source={require('../../assets/claims.png')}
                        style={{borderRadius: 20, width: 300, height: 90}}
                    />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        )
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "#f5fcff",

    },
    overlay: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
  });
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import SalesDashboard from './SalesDashboard';
import ClaimsDashboard from './ClaimsDashboard';


export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            paramName: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const paramName = this.props.navigation.getParam('param');
        this.setState({paramName});
        console.log(this.state.paramName)
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.state.paramName === 'sales'? <SalesDashboard />: <ClaimsDashboard /> }

            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

No matter what param I pass, it always renders *claimsDashboard* Screen only.

Please help  to solve this issue

Comment: if you are trying to check the state immediately in console.log after setting it you will not get the updated state. Also you can try setting the state directly in constructor. Avoiding extra `re-render` of the component

Comment: What does SalesDashboard and ClaimsDashboard render? Try setting a default value to getParam also. Print the paramName after setting the state in the callback of this.setState.

Answer (score 3):

`componentDidMount` is not the proper place to put this piece of code. It will run only once when react mounts the page, and you should notice react does not mount a new page every time you navigate to a screen. So, try placing `const paramName = this.props.navigation.getParam('param');` into your `render()` function, and there is no need to store this information on state.

If you insist in do some sort of initialization when moving to Dashboard screen, you can listen to didFocus event as per the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html).

Comment: Still no luck. Seems like the param 'sales' is not getting triggered.

Comment: What the result of `console.log(paramName)`?

Comment: Its empty. Even after two-three clicks, state is not updating. All blank

Answer (score 0):

As already said, componentDidMount won't update as it run only the first time you render the component.

To get the new params you can use `componentDidUpdate` and check the previous props with the new ones.

example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(this.props.navigation.getParam('param')!==prevProps.navigation.getParam('param')){
       //do what you need
    }
}
```

Edit.

If you don't find the param using getParam try to find it inside `this.props.navigation.state.params`

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the parameter with the following statement inside `render()` method of the Component:

```
const {navigation} = this.props;

navigation.setParams({
   param:'new value',
})
```

Inside `render()` method is the most important part.